# Add MySQL Data to bootstrap table

Tags: php, mysql

so I have a some basic table code from bootstrap updated with the column headings I would like...

```
    <table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Unit Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Assignment Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Due Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

However, I do not want the code written in manually, I need the table on this `read.php` page to display data entered from my `create.php` page. These are the database items I need displayed when user enters information...

```
<?php echo $row['id']; ?><br> Unit Name:
    <?php echo $row['unitname']; ?><br> Due Date:
    <?php echo $row['duedate']; ?><br> Assignment Name:
    <?php echo $row['assignmentname']; ?><br>
```

I have set the connection, I'm just not sure how to go about connecting the table and database...

```
<?php 

// this code will only execute after the submit button is clicked
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    
    // include the config file that we created before
    require "config.php"; 
    
    // this is called a try/catch statement 
    try {
        // FIRST: Connect to the database
        $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
        
        // SECOND: Create the SQL 
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM works";
        
        
        // THIRD: Prepare the SQL
        $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute();
        
        // FOURTH: Put it into a $result object that we can access in the page
        $result = $statement->fetchAll();

    } catch(PDOException $error) {
        // if there is an error, tell us what it is
        echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
    }   
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

use this concept

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

// Check connection
if ($mysqli -> connect_errno) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli -> connect_error;
  exit();
}

// Perform query
if ($result = $mysqli -> query("SELECT * FROM Persons")) {
    $arr_result= mysqli_fetch_array($result);
}

$mysqli -> close();

echo '
<table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
              <th scope="col">#ID</th>
              <th scope="col">Unit Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Assignment Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Due Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
';
while($arr_result){
    echo '
     <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>'.$arr_result["FirstName"].'</td>
      <td>'.$arr_result["LastName"].'</td>
      <td>'.$arr_result["mdo"].'</td>
    </tr>';
    $arr_result= mysqli_fetch_array($result);
}

echo '
    </tbody>
</table>';
?>
```

Comment: This was close, it displayed the column headings however still hasn't connected. I have edited my original post